# event.keycode support (or similar) for Internet Explorer Mobile

Tags: javascript, dom-events, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, pocket-ie

I'm trying to restrict entering certain characters in a web application meant for use on the web browser that comes with windows mobile 6.0.

I tried using `event.keycode` but it does not seem to be supported (or probably the key codes are different)?

If `event.keycode` is not supported in this version of mobileIE, how else can I restrict the end user from entering these characters into my input boxes?

Answer (score 0):

PocketIE does not support keyboard events. Keyboard event support started with AKU 6.1.4: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/05/14/internet-explorer-mobile-handles-key-events/

You may go with an alternative browser like zetaKey.